# Expo console.log commands are not shown their code line locations

Tags: reactjs, react-native, logging, expo

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.3
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
      Memory: 422.45 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.13.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node
      npm: 6.12.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28, 29
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8
```

Whenever I do any `console.log` , or whenever an error occurs, There is only `RemoteConsole.js:80`. It used to show the **file name** and the **line number** in code, where the console was written.

[image: Expo]

But in pure react native project, everything works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Line numbers for console.log statements don't work by default when using Chrome debugging. To get correct line numbers open up the Chrome Dev Tools settings, go to the "Blackboxing" tab, make sure that "Blackbox content scripts" is checked, and add expo/build/logs/RemoteConsole.js as a pattern with "Blackbox" selected.